# How can I set margin none on first child in rtl?

Tags: css, scss-lint

I have four progress bars in a vertical form in which I want margin none on the first child in rtl. So how can I set margin none on the first child ? I also tried first child property.

```css
.progress-bar-vertical:first-child {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: What to do you mean with `rtl`? The css direction property? It would really help including your form markup in the question and the css styling for the whole form as a minimal working example. It seems it's more a general question about `css` so the `scss-lint` tag is probably not the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dir property set to rtl on the html tag, you can apply RTL-specific styles like:

```
html[dir='rtl'] .progress-bar-vertical:first-child {
    margin: none;
}
```